# C# Sending UrlEndcoded Form Data

Tags: c#, httpclient

Trying to send UrlEncoded form data in Post request :

```
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myURI");

        var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        formContent.Add(new StringContent("password"), "grant_type");
        formContent.Add(new StringContent("someUser"), "username");
        formContent.Add(new StringContent("somePassword"), "password");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("token", formContent).Result;
```

For some reason the request headers contain the following :

```
 somePassword
 --7e556624-1d60-4321-a4ee-a85f6ab601c6
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=username

 someUser
 --7e556624-1d60-4321-a4ee-a85f6ab601c6
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=password
```

etc...

The Guid I guess is a boundary. However since I used urlencode it should be a '?' boundary.

In fact, if I call my service with Postman, using the same parameters and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then the request headers contain :

`app_profile=freelancer&username=someUser&password=SomePassword&grant_type=password`

So how do I achieve this with C# ?

**[EDIT]**

I managed to make it work like this. However I'd like to understand what was wrong in the original code ?

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {              
            {"username", "someUser"},
            {"password", "somePassword"},
            {"grant_type", "password"},
        };

        var formContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values)).Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you used MultipartFormDataContent.

This means that Request content type will be replaced with
**multipart/form-data; boundary={some randomly generated key}**

and the request body will be split in chunks using this {some randomly generated key}
each chunk will have its own content type.

multipart/form-data content type especially useful when sending files together with other form data.

In the edited example, you are using StringContent

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It makes sense.